# CSS Alignment Issue on Navigation Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently creating a navigation bar that expands and collapses whether the mouse is over or out of the navbar. My issue is that when the navbar is expanded, my icons are aligned to the center but I wish for them to be positioned exactly where they are before the navbar is expanded. I have them aligned to the center because the icons are not the same size and look 'out of place' without it, when the navbar is collapsed.

```js
let sidenav = document.getElementById("sidenav");
sidenav.onmouseover = function() {
  sidenav.style.width = "280px";
  document.getElementById("expand-icon").classList.add("expand");
  document.getElementById("sidenav-expand").style.textAlign = "right";
  document.getElementById("sidenav-heading").style.display = "inline-block";
  //document.getElementById("links").style.float = "left";
};
sidenav.onmouseout = function() {
  sidenav.style.width = "75px";
  document.getElementById("expand-icon").classList.remove("expand");
  document.getElementById("sidenav-expand").style.textAlign = "center";
  document.getElementById("sidenav-heading").style.display = "none";
};
```

```css
#sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1e1e2d;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: grey;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#sidenav-brand {
  padding: 25px 20px;
  background-color: #1a1a27;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#sidenav-heading h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

#sidenav-expand {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.expand {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#sidenav-links {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

#links {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#links li {
  padding: 18px;
  display: block;
}

#links li:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Navigation Bar</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6cc49d804e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="sidenav">
    <div id="sidenav-brand">
      <div id="sidenav-heading" style="display:none;">
        <h2>Expanded</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="sidenav-expand">
        <i id="expand-icon" class="fas fa-angle-double-right fa-2x"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="sidenav-links">
      <ul id="links">
        <li>
          <i class="fas fa-id-card fa-2x"></i>
        </li>
        <li>
          <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap fa-2x"></i>
        </li>
        <li>
          <i class="fas fa-briefcase fa-2x"></i>
        </li>
        <li>
          <i class="fas fa-smile-beam fa-2x"></i>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And JSFiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/h86zf4d3/

I tried to float my icons to the left as you can see from the commented out JS code, however, for some reason, this gets rid of the block display for the list items.

Comment: Please don't use such javascript code to trigger visual effect on mouse hover. Just use the `:hover` selector of `css`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it works, change the `#links{text-align:left}`
And your issue about the icon's size put the fa-fw class. it will makeall the icons the same size.

```
Check the snippest below:
```

```js
let sidenav = document.getElementById("sidenav");
sidenav.onmouseover = function() {
  sidenav.style.width = "280px";
  document.getElementById("expand-icon").classList.add("expand");
  document.getElementById("sidenav-expand").style.textAlign = "right";
  document.getElementById("sidenav-heading").style.display = "inline-block";
  //document.getElementById("links").style.float = "left";
};
sidenav.onmouseout = function() {
  sidenav.style.width = "75px";
  document.getElementById("expand-icon").classList.remove("expand");
  document.getElementById("sidenav-expand").style.textAlign = "center";
  document.getElementById("sidenav-heading").style.display = "none";
};
```

```css
#sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1e1e2d;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: grey;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#sidenav-brand {
  padding: 25px 20px;
  background-color: #1a1a27;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#sidenav-heading h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

#sidenav-expand {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.expand {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#sidenav-links {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

#links {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

#links li {
  padding: 18px;
  display: block;
}

#links li:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Navigation Bar</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6cc49d804e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="sidenav">
      <div id="sidenav-brand">
        <div id="sidenav-heading" style="display:none;">
          <h2>Expanded</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="sidenav-expand">
          <i id="expand-icon" class="fas fa-angle-double-right fa-2x"></i>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="sidenav-links">
        <ul id="links">
          <li>
            <i class="fas fa-fw fa-id-card fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
          <li>
            <i class="fas fa-fw fa-graduation-cap fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
          <li>
            <i class="fas fa-fw fa-briefcase fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
          <li>
            <i class="fas fa-fw fa-smile-beam fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `text-align: center` rule on `#links` element. Also I edited your css to add some `:hover` rules to avoid using javascript:

```css
#sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1e1e2d;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: grey;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#sidenav:hover {
  width: 280px;
}

#sidenav:hover #expand-icon {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#sidenav:hover #sidenav-heading {
  display: inline-block;
}

#sidenav #sidenav-heading {
  display: none;
}

#sidenav-brand {
  padding: 25px 20px;
  background-color: #1a1a27;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#sidenav-heading h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

#sidenav-expand {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

#sidenav-links {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

#links {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#links li {
  padding: 18px 20px;
  /* <-- Add some padding*/
  display: block;
}

#links li:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Navigation Bar</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6cc49d804e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="sidenav">
    <div id="sidenav-brand">
      <div id="sidenav-heading">
        <h2>Expanded</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="sidenav-expand">
        <i id="expand-icon" class="fas fa-angle-double-right fa-2x"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="sidenav-links">
      <ul id="links">
        <li>
          <i class="fas fa-id-card fa-2x"></i>
        </li>
        <li>
          <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap fa-2x"></i>
        </li>
        <li>
          <i class="fas fa-briefcase fa-2x"></i>
        </li>
        <li>
          <i class="fas fa-smile-beam fa-2x"></i>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am aware of this but when doing so, the icons on the collapsed navbar are no longer positioned in the center and doesn't look 'right' to me. I know this is a small issue but I would like it to be centered when the navbar is collapsed and the icons to stay where they are when expanded.

Comment: @JLi_2398 What about keeping the `text-align: center` there but just adding `float: left` below it? See my answer for a demonstration.

Comment: @JLi_2398 I updated my answer using some padding and removing the javascript part ;)

Answer (score 0):

why not just placing them to left ?

```
#links li{
  text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: This removes the center positioning for the icons in the collapsed navbar. I want the icons to be centered on collapsed but stay where they are when expanded

Comment: In your jsfiddle, nothing change when I change the position. Anyway, you can apply that style on mouseover so li elements will be aligned left !

Answer (score 0):

I've simpy added `float: left` to the CSS for `#links` and it looks fine to me.

They are still center-aligned on the collapsed version, because I haven't removed the line directly above it which says `text-align: center;`. However, they no longer change position when the menu opens.

See the snippet below:

```js
let sidenav = document.getElementById("sidenav");
sidenav.onmouseover = function() {
  sidenav.style.width = "280px";
  document.getElementById("expand-icon").classList.add("expand");
  document.getElementById("sidenav-expand").style.textAlign = "right";
  document.getElementById("sidenav-heading").style.display = "inline-block";
};
sidenav.onmouseout = function() {
  sidenav.style.width = "75px";
  document.getElementById("expand-icon").classList.remove("expand");
  document.getElementById("sidenav-expand").style.textAlign = "center";
  document.getElementById("sidenav-heading").style.display = "none";
};
```

```css
#sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1e1e2d;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: grey;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#sidenav-brand {
  padding: 25px 20px;
  background-color: #1a1a27;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#sidenav-heading h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

#sidenav-expand {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.expand {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#sidenav-links {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

#links {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

#links li {
  padding: 18px;
  display: block;
}

#links li:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Navigation Bar</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6cc49d804e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="sidenav">
    <div id="sidenav-brand">
      <div id="sidenav-heading" style="display:none;">
        <h2>Expanded</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="sidenav-expand">
        <i id="expand-icon" class="fas fa-angle-double-right fa-2x"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="sidenav-links">
      <ul id="links">
        <li>
          <i class="fas fa-id-card fa-2x"></i>
        </li>
        <li>
          <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap fa-2x"></i>
        </li>
        <li>
          <i class="fas fa-briefcase fa-2x"></i>
        </li>
        <li>
          <i class="fas fa-smile-beam fa-2x"></i>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The positioning is fine but this gets rid of the block display for each list item, which will be needed for links later.